# I keep getting null exception when the parameter is supposed to be empty when I create new data

Tags: java, null

I'm having trouble with my doPost method in my servlet. I'm doing a simple system with java and oracle for its database. And in database, attribute rph_id is auto-increment, so in Java, when I want to create a new set of data, the rph_id is supposed to be empty, right?

The codes worked before but now it doesn't work anymore. It keeps giving null exception.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{

    int rph_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rph_id"));
    String rph_date = request.getParameter("rph_date");
    String rph_time = request.getParameter("rph_time");
    String rph_type = request.getParameter("rph_type");
    int teacher_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("teacher_id"));
    int subject_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("subject_id"));
    String rph_submitstatus = null;
    String rph_comment = null;

    RPHS rph = new RPHS(rph_date, rph_time, rph_type, rph_submitstatus, rph_comment, teacher_id, subject_id, false);
    rph = RphDAO.getRph(rph);
}
```

I keep getting null at line `int rph_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rph_id"));`

the `rph_id` is auto-increment in the database. It's an attribute in the parent class, and I have to use in the child class.

Comment: If you're *expecting* it to be null, then why are you trying to parse it?

Comment: If I remove it, I will get error because after the codes, I have a method to create new data. And in that method, I have to use the attribute rph_id because it is inheritance. So, I need rph_id (att from the parent) for the child.

Comment: It doesn't look like you use `rph_id`. Do you need to try to do anything?

Comment: I use it for the child class and if removed, I will get error for the rph_id, and this is the object for the child class: Events event = new Events(rph_id, rph_date, rph_time, rph_type, rph_submitstatus, rph_comment, teacher_id, subject_id, false, event_description);

Answer (score 1):

You're saying that it's auto-increment key at DB, so why are you trying to get it from request parameters ?  You can't get a value from there if you didn't ever set a value , or set by a html form etc..

You should get it from your RPHS object after insert.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    //int rph_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rph_id"));
    ..
    ..

    RPHS rph = new RPHS(rph_date, rph_time, rph_type, rph_submitstatus, rph_comment, teacher_id, subject_id, false);
    rph = RphDAO.getRph(rph);

    int rph_id=rph.getRphId();
}
```

Comment: assuming `getRph` does the insert (if so, consider changing the name of that method, `get` does not sound like `INSERT`) and returns the auto-incremented id

Comment: I removed the line and also the attribute from the child class (replaced it with 0 because that's what Java suggested me). It works fine! Can you explain to me why 0 works? How does it replace the rph_id attribute?

Comment: I can't say that without seeing rest of the code. And i think you should take notice of Thilo's suggestion about method names.

Comment: getRph is to check whether my boolean is true or false. My insert method is after the getRph. Thank you to both of you.